# Need help making Structure in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

May someone help me with that one:
[image]

I don't got it myself.

Thanks
Greetings KillTrot

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. This applies to all of your three questions so far.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new to LaTex as well i'm new to this forum.

Might you explain, how exactly I can help you? 
I don't know where to start with my problem, cause it have to "fit" from two sites and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, got it myself...

```
\chemfig{...*6(-(-[6]\lewis{40,O}(-[6]B(-[4]HO)(-[0]OH)(-[6]\lewis{40,O}(-[6](*6(-...))))))-(*6(-(-[6]OH)-(*6(-(-[6]\lewis{40,O}(-[6]B(-[4]HO)(-[0]OH)(-[6]\lewis{40,O}(-[6]([:30]*6(-...))(*6(-(*6(-(-[2]OH)-(*6(-))))))))))-...)))))}
```

resolves in:
[image]

Anyways, thanks for helping.